# SLDS Lightning static Resource not loading

Tags: lightning-design-system, slds

Am trying to apply CSS for a page using SLDS which is refered from static resource but am unable to make it work. Please help[image: static resource for SLDS]

Am refering the above resource in .app page as below

```
<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css"/>
<div class="slds">
    <div class="slds-page-header">
    <p class="slds-page-header__Title" title="Race Tracker">Race Tracker</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-m-around--small slds-p-top--large">
    <c.newRace />
    </div>
    <div class="slds-m-around--small slds-p-top--large">
     <c.RaceList />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please let me know where are you using the component? In a visualforce page or in a lightning app under the context one/one.app in the url?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against using SLDS as a static resource in your case as this is no longer the best practice.

Since Winter '17, you can just extends `force:slds` ([documentation here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_lightning_slds.htm)) in you app such as this:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
```

Doing so will automatically add the right SLDS resources and you will not have to worry about SLDS upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the static resource name followed by file Path of CSS inside SLDS Zip file.

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.SLDS + '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css'}" />
```

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ltng_require.htm)

Comment: i tried this                                                                                          `<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.min.css"/>` but this is not working

Comment: Please try this <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.SLDS + '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css'}" />

Comment: /resource/SLDS/ no need to mention

Comment: Still not working i have used `<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.SLDS + '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.min.css'}" />`

Comment: It should be working, i have verified its working Fine .

Comment: can u try with this code .   <aura:application extends="force:slds">
</aura:application>     // your above code with ltng:require